# How to decode string to UTF-8 correctly?

Tags: android

my server sends string in UTF-8, but instead of "testing ok" I got "[B@417f6d00". I used this code for decode, but not helped:

```
String s = URLDecoder.decode(bytes.toString(), "UTF-8");
```

Maybe "bytes.toString()" is wrong? Please help.

Comment: Yes, `bytes.toString()` is incorrect. Where is that `byte[]` coming from? Try `new String(bytes, "UTF-8")`.

Comment: Thanks, it works URLDecoder.decode(bytes.toString(), "UTF-8");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
String s = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```